Как писать mobx на классовых компонентах react.ts
Хочу написать на react.ts mobx class component, но вылезает ошибка
Cannot access 'Context' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Context' before initialization
Вот код где вылезает ошибка:
//Header.tsx
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react'
import '../style/Home.scss'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Google from '../images/Google.png'
import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import Round from '../images/round.png'
import { Context } from '..'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

interface ExampleState {
  showAuth: boolean;
  showReg: boolean;
  showReg2: boolean;
  email:string;
  password:string;
}
@observer

export default class Header extends React.Component<{}, ExampleState> {

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showAuth: false,
      showReg: false,
      showReg2: false,
      email:'',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  static store = Context

  handleRegistration = (store: any) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    store.registration('surname', 'name', 'lastname', email, password, 'color');
  };


  handleCloseAuth = () => {
    this.setState({ showAuth: false });
  };

  handleShowAuth = () => {
    this.setState({ showAuth: true });
  };

  handleCloseReg = () => {
    this.setState({ showReg: false });
  };

  handleShowReg = () => {
    this.setState({ showReg: true });
  };

  handleCloseReg2 = () => {
    this.setState({ showReg2: false });
  };

  handleShowReg2 = () => {
    this.setState({ showReg2: true });
    this.setState({ showReg: false })
  };

  googleAuth = () => {
    window.open(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/google/callback`, "_self");
  };


  render() {
    const { showAuth } = this.state;
    const { showReg } = this.state;
    const { showReg2 } = this.state;
    const { email } = this.state;
    const { password } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="header__cont">
          <div className="header__cont__left">
            <p onClick={this.handleShowAuth}>Авторизация</p>
          </div>
          <div className="header__cont__center">
            <h1>BOOKSWAP</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="header__cont__right">
            <p onClick={this.handleShowReg}>Регистрация</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Modal show={showAuth} onHide={this.handleCloseAuth}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton className="custom-close-button">
            <Modal.Title style={{margin:'0 auto', textAlign:'center', marginLeft:'8.5rem'}}>Авторизация</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body style={{height:'420px'}}>
            <button className='btn-google' onClick={this.googleAuth}>
              <div>
                <img src={Google} alt="Google" />
                <p>Войти через Google</p>
              </div>
            </button>
            <div style={{display:'flex', margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'10px'}}>
              <div className="horizontal-line"></div>
              <p style={{color:'#F0A650'}}>или</p>
              <div className="horizontal-line"></div>
            </div>
            <FloatingLabel
              controlId="floatingInput"
              label="Email"
              className="mb-3"
              style={{color:'#F0A650'}}
            >
              <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Пароль" style={{color:'#F0A650'}}>
              <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <p className='a' style={{color:'#F0A650', fontWeight:'600', marginTop:'5px', fontSize:'16px'}}>Забыл пароль?</p>
            <button className='btn-auth' style={{marginTop:'-5px'}}>Авторизоваться</button>
            <p style={{display:'flex', marginTop:'10px'}}>Нет аккаунта?<p className='a' style={{color:'#F0A650', fontWeight:'600', marginLeft:'5px', fontSize:'16px'}}>Создать аккаунт</p></p>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
        <Modal show={showReg} onHide={this.handleCloseReg}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton className="custom-close-button">
            <Modal.Title style={{margin:'0 auto', textAlign:'center', marginLeft:'9rem'}}>Регистрация</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body style={{height:'470px'}}>
            <button className='btn-google'>
              <div>
                <img src={Google} alt="Google" />
                <p>Зарегистрироваться через Google</p>
              </div>
            </button>
            <div style={{display:'flex', margin:'0 auto', marginTop:'10px'}}>
              <div className="horizontal-line"></div>
              <p style={{color:'#F0A650'}}>или</p>
              <div className="horizontal-line"></div>
            </div>
            <FloatingLabel
              controlId="floatingInput"
              label="Email"
              className="mb-3"
              style={{color:'#F0A650'}}
            >
              <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="name@example.com"  value={this.state.email}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}/>
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Пароль" style={{color:'#F0A650'}}>
              <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}/>
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Повторите пароль" style={{color:'#F0A650', marginTop:'15px'}}>
              <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <button className='btn-auth' style={{marginTop:'15px'}} onClick={this.handleRegistration}>Зарегистрироваться</button>
            <p style={{display:'flex', marginTop:'10px'}}>Есть аккаунт?<p className='a' style={{color:'#F0A650', fontWeight:'600', marginLeft:'5px', fontSize:'16px'}}>Войти</p></p>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
        <Modal show={showReg2} onHide={this.handleCloseReg2}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton className="custom-close-button">
            <Modal.Title style={{margin:'0 auto', textAlign:'center', marginLeft:'9rem'}}>Регистрация</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body style={{height:'560px'}}>
            <div style={{margin:'0 auto', display:'flex', marginBottom:'15px'}}>
              <Image src={Round} roundedCircle style={{width:'8rem', margin:'0 auto'}}/>
            </div>
            <FloatingLabel
              controlId="floatingInput"
              label="Фамилия"
              className="mb-3"
              style={{color:'#F0A650'}}
            >
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="name@example.com" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Имя" style={{color:'#F0A650'}}>
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Отчество" style={{color:'#F0A650', marginTop:'15px'}}>
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </FloatingLabel>
            <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3" style={{color:'#F0A650', marginTop:'10px'}}>
              <Form.Label>Аватар пользователя</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="file" />
            </Form.Group>
            <button className='btn-auth' style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>Зарегистрироваться</button>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//store.ts
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
import { User } from "../model/User";
import AuthService from "../service/AuthService";
import api from "../http";

interface Credentials {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export default class Store {
    user: Credentials = { email: '', password: '' };
    error?: string[] = [];
    isAuth = false;
    isLoading = false;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setAuth(bool: boolean) {
        this.isAuth = bool;
    }

    setUser(user: Credentials) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    setLoading(bool: boolean) {
        this.isLoading = bool;
    }

    setError(error?: string[]) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    async registration(surname: string, name: string, lastname: string, email: string, password: string, color: string) {
        try {
            this.setError([]);
            const { data } = await AuthService.registration(surname, name, lastname, email, password, color);
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken);
            this.setAuth(true);
            const credentials: Credentials = { email: data.user.email, password: data.user.password };
            this.setUser(credentials);
            return data;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            let error: any = e;
            this.setError(error.response.data.message);
        }
    }
}

код, где упоминается Header.tsx:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import '../style/Home.scss';
import MyCarousel from '../components/Carousel';
import Store from '../store/store'; 

const store = new Store(); 

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="home__cont">
          <Header/>
          <MyCarousel />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//app.tsx
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './page/Home';
import { Reg } from './components/Reg';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;

//index.tsx
// index.ts
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Store from './store/store';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

interface State {
  store: Store
}

const store = new Store()
export const Context = createContext<State>({
  store,
})

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Context.Provider value={{
      store
    }}>
        <App />
    </Context.Provider>  
  </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bit.ly/CRA-vitals
reportWebVitals();

